# Need to be able to print all pages in my survey - not just the last page

Tags: printing

I'm currently deploying a survey with several pages, I embedded the javascript print button, but when I click on this I only get what is between the last two page breaks.  I need my customers to be able to print the whole document and not the last two pages, is there something I can add to the javascript to make it print between all page breaks?

This is the javascript I am using:

```
 <form> <input type="button" value="Print"  onClick="window.print()"></form>
```

Comment: Something went wrong with the code :)

Comment: Yes, not sure what, but I did add it to the original question.  This is the code:  <form> <input type="button" value="Print"  onClick="window.print()"></form>

Comment: What is the HTML of your survey?

Comment: Could you perhaps reproduce the issue in a JsFiddle?